# Fake HTTP Post Requests

Tags: java, php, http, curl

My question is very similar to this one [Fake HTTP Get Requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210873/fake-http-get-requests)

Except im looking for a more detailed response to one of the answers there:

> Yes - it is technically possible to spoof your IP address so the
>   packets look like they've come from elsewhere.
>
> No - in that it is unlikely to be useful.

The answerer is wrong in that, it actually has usefulness in my scenario.

How can you **spoof the IP address in an HTTP Post request**, **not expecting any response?**

Comment: I have added details to the accepted answer of that other question. That question *is* a duplicate of this (it being GET/POST makes absolutely zero difference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address is an information at a lower level than your HTTP connection, so to properly fake the IP address, you need something that will let you "rewrite" that information in the IP packet your network card sends out.

Sending out a fake HTTP header while your network packets still carry your real IP address isn't going to help in any way, a proper IP filter will detect you (as pointed out in the answer you mentioned).

I can't help you more on this: you need to find a separate tool that will craft your packets *after* you have established the TCP connection over which you are going to send your POST data, and I don't know any such tool.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you are doing you need to set a header for Remote_Addr with the IP you wish to use. Obviously this doesn't obfuscate your actual IP at the network level.

With curl in linux:

`curl --header "Remote_Addr: 10.10.10.10" --data "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://example.com/resource`

Comment: Replies are based on the network packets, not the Remote_Addr header, so the replies will still go to you and the traffic will be traceable back to your real IP.

Comment: Which is what I meant by "this doesn't obfuscate your actual IP at the network level."

Comment: Doesn't work how? Doesn't actually spoof your IP? No, clearly. What do you want to do? The IP spoofing is a separate issue from the POST request.

Comment: If you just want to spoof your IP: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ip-spoofing

Comment: Doesn't work as in i created a simple form on my website, and used CURL with the header "REMOTE_ADDR". The form emailed me after posting and the remote addr was not the one i provided in the header.

Comment: The question was asking how to spoof the IP address, and your answer says (correctly) that your code does not obfuscate the IP address. That means it does not do what was asked.